# JavaScript: как удалить решётку (#) из хэша, добавляемую при установке существующего хэша в пустую строку

Tags: javascript

Как удалить решётку (#) из хэша, добавляемую при установке существующего хэша в пустую строку:

```
location.hash = 'blablabla';

location.hash = '';
```

После исполнения указанного кода в адресной строке остаётся решётка (#). Как её удалить?

Comment: Опишите на примере действия которые выполняете. А то я пока не совсем понимаю вопрос

Comment: Суть такая же как и в листинге выше: установлен хэш, нужно его удалить, чтобы ничего не осталось, включая решётку. Вариант, предложенный @VladimirMorulus, подходит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
history.pushState("",document.title,window.location.pathname+window.location.search);
```